# Multiple OrderBy in SQLiteDatabase.Query Method

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by

I am using the query method of `SQLiteDatabase`. I need help with the *orderBy* parameter of this method.

`Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(tableName, tableColumns, whereClause, whereArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);`

```
public Cursor getAllCustomexp(int TID) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(false, CEXP_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_CEID, FLD_CETID, FLD_CEEID, FLD_CEMID,
            FLD_CEAMT, FLD_CESEL}, FLD_CETID + " = " + TID, null,
            null, null, FLD_CEEID, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Question 1:
In the above query the result set will be sorted by `FLD_CEEID` in ascending or descending order ?

Question 2:
If I need to order the result set first by `FLD_CEEID` and then by `FLD_CEMID` how should i construct the order by parameter of this query.

Is it possible to do multiple order by using this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby):

> If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an
>   ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is
>   undefined. Or, if a SELECT statement does have an ORDER BY clause,
>   then the list of expressions attached to the ORDER BY determine the
>   order in which rows are returned to the user. Rows are first sorted
>   based on the results of evaluating the left-most expression in the
>   ORDER BY list, then ties are broken by evaluating the second left-most
>   expression and so on. The order in which two rows for which all ORDER
>   BY expressions evaluate to equal values are returned is undefined.
>   Each ORDER BY expression may be optionally followed by one of the
>   keywords ASC (smaller values are returned first) or DESC (larger
>   values are returned first). If neither ASC or DESC are specified, rows
>   are sorted in ascending (smaller values first) order by default.

Answer 1: Result set will be sorted in ascending order.

Answer 2:

```
String orderBy = FLD_CEEID + " ASC, " + FLD_CEMID + " ASC";
db.query(false, CEXP_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_CEID, FLD_CETID, FLD_CEEID, FLD_CEMID,
        FLD_CEAMT, FLD_CESEL}, FLD_CETID + " = " + TID, null,
        null, null, orderBy, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like in `SQL Select Order By`. You can find details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by_(SQL) .